# SonarQube Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false"

Tags: java, sonarqube

[SonarQube screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJMTV.png)

> 99. on the line 'implies "ok" is false' and 102. i get the error 'expression is always false' on the line. how can I change this situation?

iIneed this part in my code. I couldn't find a solution method.

Comment: you are already testing if prj.getMasterData() == null before. if prj is null there, it'll throw an NPE, so it will never reach the if ( prj == null ) test. The place where you do that test, it is impossible for prj to be null

Answer (score 1):

The right way to rewrite your code, and so getting rid of SonarQube suggestions, is:

```java
if ((null != prj) && (null != prj.getMasterData()) {
  ECEOAuthDefs authDefs = new ECEOAuthDefs();
  authDefs.setDescription(prj.getCode());
}
```

SQ is telling you that if you enter the `if condition` it is because `prj` is not null, so it is not useful test it again.